# Unexpected behaviour using NSUserDefaults with asynchronous UrlConnections

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsuserdefaults

I have the following code for an asynchronous UrlConnections. If the request fails,
I add a  `NSString`to an a `NSMutableArray` that gets saved in the `NSUserDefaults`. 
The first time it adds correctly, but the second times it throws an error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

**The code is:**

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:mainQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        if (!error) {
           //something
        }
        else {

            NSMutableArray *unprocessedSubscription=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"unprocessedSubscription"];
            if(unprocessedSubscription==nil)
                unprocessedSubscription=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSString * subscriptionToAdd=@"something";
            [unprocessedSubscription addObject:subscriptionToAdd];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:unprocessedSubscription forKey:@"unprocessedSubscription"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Why a vote down? I am new to this website and to posting questions here, give me the reason please so i can improve in asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the NSArray that is returned to a NSMutableArray

```
NSArray *unprocessedSubscription=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"unprocessedSubscription"];

NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:unprocessedSubscription]
```

Comment: The cast won't have any effect whatsoever.

Comment: You should explain what is the need for that cast and how would that solve the issue than editing the answer.

Comment: Why? The cast didn't work and I edited my answer with a solution that worked.

Comment: Oh thats great, i was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the returned value is unmutable, what you can do is create a mutable array everytime and add objects if there are already saved values in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSMutableArray *unprocessedSubscription=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray * storedValues = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"unprocessedSubscription"];
if(storedValues != nil){
[unprocessedSubscription addObjectsFromArray:storedValues];
}
 NSString * subscriptionToAdd=@"something";
 [unprocessedSubscription addObject:subscriptionToAdd];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:unprocessedSubscription forKey:@"unprocessedSubscription"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your

```
NSMutableArray *unprocessedSubscription=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"unprocessedSubscription"];
```

to

```
NSMutableArray *unprocessedSubscription=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"unprocessedSubscription"] mutableCopy];
```